# How does migrating questions affect your reputation?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration

I've never had a question migrated before, but I was curious to know how it would affect your reputation. Does it add/subtract? If it adds, why?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I tried searching, but to no avail. I see it's a duplicate now.